# How can I skip the header in Python?

Tags: python

This is my code. I am trying to

- import the data from net
- Skip 12 lines
- Store the rest of the data in a variable and perform some simple operations.

  ```
   import urllib2 

   airtemp = urllib2.urlopen('http://coastwatch.glerl.noaa.gov/ftp/glsea/avgtemps/2013/glsea-temps2013_1024.dat').read(30000)
   airtemp = airtemp.split("\n")

   lineskip1 = 0
   for line in airtemp:
       if lineskip1 <12:
           continue
       print line
       lineskip1+=1
  ```

But I'm not able to print the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are continuing the loop without incrementing `lineskip1`, so the condition is always true.

```
lineskip1 = 0
for line in airtemp:
    lineskip1 += 1
    if lineskip1 <= 12:  # Skip lines numbered 1 through 12
        continue
    print line
```

A better method is to use `enumerate` to count the lines for you.

```
for i, line in enumerate(airtemp):
    if i < 12:  # Skip lines numbered 0 through 11
        continue
    print line
```

or to use `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice
for line in islice(airtemp, 12, None):  # Skip lines numbered 0 through 11
    print line
```

Comment: @chepner Did you mean `i <= 11` in the above code that shows the usage of enumerate?

Comment: OK, I think I fixed the all the details I overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple list slice will work:

```
for line in airtemp[12:]: # start at line 13
   print line
```